# How to get a jwt token from url in header? Using OpenAM and Oauth2

Tags: oauth, token, jwt, openam

[Related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574101/openam-implict-grant-flow-username)

I configured OpenAM as Oauth2 Authorization Provider and also setup a Oauth2 Client on the same instance via " OAuth 2.0/OpenID Connect Client". As scope i choose "openid" and as Response_type "id_token" so that my authorize URL Looks like the following: http://FQDN:PORT/OpenAMTest/oauth2/authorize?client_id=jwt-bearer-client&response_type=id_token&scope=openid

Now when i enter the URL I get the OpenAM Login Screen, then I enter the credentials and get asked if i want to allow this application to request my private Infos. When I press "allow" a JWT token gets generated. I see that in the URL (id_token=eyAidHlw...) but I want this JWT token to be in the HTTP Header so that i can later on in my application validate it by reading it from the request. Do you know how this is possible?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

After OpenAM authenticate the user it makes a redirect to your application with token as URL parameter. I'm afraid it cannot instruct your browser to send the token as HTTP header with redirect. It is a limitation in all browsers.